# Accessing the first letter of a string element of a list using indeces

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm programming with Python (3.x) and I'd like to go through a list of strings checking if the first letter of the following list element is lowercase (and then joining the current and the following element).

My problem is how to access the first letter of the following list element. 
I tried "list[i+1][0]" and also  "(list[i+1])[0]", but none of them worked. 
Is there a way to solve this with indices, or is there a function?

My code looks a bit like this:

```
i=0
while i<len(list)
  if list[i+1][0].islower():
    list[i].append(list[i+1])
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please let us know *how* things failed to work.  Did you get an error message? Did you get unexpected output?

Comment: You definitely will want to avoid using reserved keywords such as `list`, `dict`, etc as variable names.

Comment: What do you want to have happen if you encounter a word that has an uppercase first letter?

Comment: What do you want the behaviour to be if the first string in the list is lowercase?

Comment: It's probably best if you show us a sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over pairs, each pair containing the current element and the next element of your list:

```
for cur, nxt in zip(myList, myList[1:]):
    if nxt[0].islower():
        #do something in the case the next element starts with a lowercase letter
        continue
    #do something otherwise
```

---

Now for your problem at hand about joining, I don't see the need to have a look-ahead buffer. I hope the following code has the desired behaviour:

```
myList = ['one', 'two', 'Three', 'four', 'Five']
outList = []
for ele in myList:
    if ele and ele[0].islower() and outList:
        outList[-1] += ele
        continue
    outList.append(ele)
print(outList)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you can iterate over pairs... Well, that's a whole new thing to me! I'll try it as soon as possible! Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

You have a boundary issue. If i = len(list) - 1, then list[i] is in the list, but list[i+1] is the same as list[len(list)], which is NOT in the list. Since there is no element following list[len(list)-1], it should exit the loop.

Try `while i < len(list) - 1`

Also, note that `list` is a special term in Python. Don't name your list "list". The "Pythonic" generic names for variables are "spam", "eggs", and "ham", but you should pick something more descriptive.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. I had noticed that "list" is a special term in Python, but forgot to pay attention to it when trying to describe my code as simple as possible. Thanks anyways!